# XPATH inside IMPORTXML with double quotation marks in query

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, double-quotes

I am trying to scrape data from a website to Google Sheets but because of the double quotes in the xpath_query on "compTable" I keep a formula parse error. When I try do single quotes ie. 'compTable' I get the error imported content is empty. Is there a way I can handle double quotations in xpath inside of an importxml function and get this function to not return an error?

=IMPORTXML("https://www.levels.fyi/comp.html?track=Software%20Engineer&search=sydney&city=1311","//*[@id="compTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/a")

For context I am trying to use this formula to get the company name from the table in the url e.g. Google, Amazon, Canva. Ultimately I want to scrape this website to create a Google Sheet with each row of the table in this URL so that I have each data point (company name, total compensation, level etc.) on each row of my Google Sheet.

Comment: Change with simple quote `[@id='compTable']` . however this site needs javascript and get informations via ajax method ... you can't use native functions. See here : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun

Comment: If you try `=importhtml(url,"table",1)` you will get an empty table with only the headers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.levels.fyi/comp.html?track=Software%20Engineer&search=sydney&city=1311", 
 "//*[@id='compTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/a")
```